# Django Tastypie - Angular login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, tastypie

I've got a problem where I don't to get any connection to the django-server. In the browser console I'm getting a error msg:

[![console error][1]][1]

I'm using tastypie and have a userResource class:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

class Meta:
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
    resource_name = 'user'

def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
        url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
    ]

def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True
            })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'disabled',
                }, HttpForbidden )
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,
            'reason': 'incorrect',
            }, HttpUnauthorized )

def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
    if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
        logout(request)
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False }, HttpUnauthorized)
```

And then in my client I've got a loginController that is supposed to sent a POST data with a username and password.
loginController:

```
    module.controller('LoginController', ['$scope','$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
              method: 'POST',
              data: {'username' : 'test', 'password' : 'test123' },
              url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log("OK Respone");
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.orders = response.data.objects;
              }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log("NO Response");
        });
 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide to the backend a list of allowed hosts whose requests will be handled. Check [this](https://gist.github.com/robhudson/3848832) gist for a code snippet, or consider using the [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) package that solves the Cross-Domain requests problem.

Using `django-cors-headers` you can configure what domains are allowed to make requests, either by specifying in one by one, or using a regular expression (which is pretty useful in case you will have many subdomains that access the same API and there are many other options.

Good luck!

Comment: I've solved it with the Cross, It was the slash at the end of the request URL. But the "angular.js:11442 POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/ 500 (Internal Server Error)" still appears, do you thing is has to do with the backend or client to do?

Comment: in console, press on the failed request and switch to Response tab to see what the error is and where does it happen in your code.